# When does $L_1$ convergence imply compact convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

Consider a metric space $X$, endow it with its Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{X}$ and a Borel measure $\mu$. Consider measurabe (real-valued) functions $f_n$ and $f$, assume that
$$
\Vert f_n - f \Vert_1= \int_X |f_n(x)-f(x)| d\mu(x) \to 0, \quad n \to \infty.
$$
Under which conditions the above $L^1$-convergence assumption entails compact convergence, i.e.
$$
\sup_{x \in K}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0, \quad n \to \infty,
$$
for all compact $K \subset X$? I guess that even continuity conditions on $f_n$ and $f$ may not be sufficient. Am I wrong?

Comment: Very very rarely. $L^{1}$ convergence does not even imply point-wise convergence.

Comment: Yes, I guess so, in general $L^1$ convergence only allows us to deduce pointwise convergence of subsequences. So I was guessing whether in some partifcular cases we can anyway deduce pointwise convergence and (by continuity) extend it to uniform convergence over compacta.

Comment: If $f,f_n$ are analytic in an open disk $D$ and if $\int_D |f_n-f| \to 0$ then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of the disk.